# How do I catch a PHP mysqli_stmt error?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to catch mysqli_stmt errors like following pseudocode:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

try{
   $stmt=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO test(test_1, test_2) VALUES (?, ?)');
   $stmt->bind_param("is", $example_variable1, $example_variable2);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();
   echo 'data inserted successful, everything ok!';
}catch(mysqliError $e){
   echo 'please retry later!';
}
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: You might need to check the return value of each method to trap error. Or use a custom-built class to wrap `mysqli_stmt` and throw you own exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, you should **[never catch mysqli errors only to show such a message](http://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch)** as it's extremely inefficient (wrapping every query in try-catch!) and harmful (because error have to be logged, not dismissed silently).

Instead, you can define a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and let it log the error message and then show this 'please retry later' text. Surely you want it to show when any query fails, not only one.

And after you got this, just set mysqli in exception mode,

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

this line have to be added before mysqli connect.

And you can use this example code to handle errors on your site. Note that during development, just comment the first line out.

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    error_log("$errstr in $errfile:$errline");
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    echo 'please retry later!';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` means *Throw mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings*. PHP always so intuitive...

Comment: Thank you for replying, can you show me a code example please?